# Magento 2 - Product category id on success

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, order-success-page

How can I get the **category id** of the products ordered on the `success.phtml` page. I have managed to get other bits of data but cant find the category id.

I need to check the category so i can post to a third parties **API** only if a product from a specific category has been purchased.

My **OOP** knowledge isn't the best. So please be patient lol

Comment: so you want category IDs for each product of that particular order on `success.phtml` page?

Comment: yes or at least be able to check for "X" id exists, if true then post to API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
echo  "Order ID:".$orderId."<br/>";

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach($items as $i):
    $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($i->getProductId());
    $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
endforeach;

?>
```

You will get all category IDs for that particular product in `$categoryIds`. **But again I won't recommend to do this using Object Manager directly. Instead of doing this please create your block and pass detail from there and you can retrieve in this file.**

Comment: This didnt seem to work. The array inside `$items` is always empty  here is what i am trying to do to show what is inside the array.
`$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);

    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($items);
    echo "</pre>";`

Comment: I edit my answer. Please print `$_product` object and check for `categopry_ids`. Thanks

Comment: Printing `$_product` does not work either. If i try to print `$items` the array is empty so i think that is why printing `$_product` does not work

Comment: edit my code again... `$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();`.. it should work

Comment: That gives me a empty `$items` varible too

Comment: it seems like order is not loading by order ID. I changed my code to `loadByIncrementId`. Please try again. Thanks

Comment: is it resolved?

Comment: Sorry i didnt confirm, i didnt get to test the new code yesterday but it works a charm.

Comment: please upvote the answer if it's useful.